# Understaning Fisher’s combined probability test in my analysis

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, genetics, combining-p-values

I'm trying to understand Fisher's combined probability test, especially how I used it in my analysis. I have 25 datasets, each one containing genomic data from cancer patients. I conducted a differential expression analysis on each dataset (analysis the produces a log fold change and p-value for each gene, showing the most significant genes in a comparison between two different groups or conditions). I used Fisher's combined probability test, and in the end, each gene had just one p-value, and their log fold changes were averaged. How does Fisher's test produce just one p-value for each gene? And how does this relate to the formula of the method?

Here is was I have so far though. How accurate am I ?

This method aggregates individual p-values from multiple tests into a single representative p-value. Fisher's combined probability test operates under the principle that when multiple independent tests of the same hypothesis yield small p-values, the evidence against the null hypothesis is stronger than any individual test suggests. The formula for Fisher's method is:
\begin{equation}
X_{2k}^2 = -2 \sum_{i=1}^k ln(p_i)
\end{equation}

where $p_i$ represents the individual p-values. The resultant chi-squared statistic, with $2k$ degrees of freedom (where $k$ is the number of tests being combined), produces a unified p-value (for each gene, in this particular case).